# Access mail item OWA browser C#

Tags: c#, browser, outlook-web-app

My scenario goes like this: Suppose a user is travelling somewhere he has to send a mail by his laptop/tablet using OWA. I have to write some program in C# which can access the mail which is being send.

In other words any example by which I can learn how to customize Outlook web access interface..

How can I achieve it...

Any help or guideline would be appreciated.

Comment: A browser plugin is about the only way assuming the OWA site is encrypted. But what you're basically asking is how to write a piece of malware that can steal website information.

Comment: Thank you for reply. My intention is not like writing malware..

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does provide an interop assemblies to interface with Outlook. The documentation is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb652780.aspx

There is an example of the usage here : [outlook download email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080617/outlook-download-email-body)

Comment: Thank you for reply.. I do not want to write add-in for outlook. It should extend the outlook web access.